# In PaperJS is it possible to set the length of a straight line path explicitly?

Tags: javascript, canvas, vector-graphics, paperjs

From what I can see it looks like the only way to change the length of a single Path is to `path.scale(x)` it. However I want to make the line's length oscillate slightly around its original length, which is difficult to do with `scale`, because if you feed it random values you will in effect end up with its length taking a random walk, potentially ending up far away from its original length.

is it possible to set the length of a line path explicitly, something like `path.length = 10`? According to the documentation it doesn't seem like this is possible. Why not?? And what would be the best way to achieve my desired outcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by noting that paths in paperjs are not geometric shapes though they may have been specified as one. They are arrays of segment points; that's why setting the length of a line directly is not possible. A line has two segment points - one for the start and one for the end of the line. By manipulating the second segment point you can adjust the length of the line. This [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) (the following code) illustrates how to do so. To adjust the length of the original line uncomment the last line of code.

```
line = new Path.Line([100,100], [200, 300]);
line.strokeColor = 'black';
line.strokeWidth = 5;

// paths in paper are arrays of segments, not instances of
// circle or line or rectangle. so find the vector that
// represents the delta between the first point and the
// second point.
vector = line.segments[0].point - line.segments[1].point;

// adjustment for the line - this would vary in your case
factor = 0.9;

// I'm drawing a new line here to make it easy to see
p0 = line.segments[0].point;
p1 = p0 - vector * factor;

newline = new Path.Line(p0, p1);
newline.strokeColor = 'red';
newline.strokeWidth = 2;

// but to adjust your original line just use the following
//line.segments[1].point = p1;
```

You can store the original vector, if you choose to do so, in the property `line.data` which is an empty object that paper creates for whatever the user wishes. So `line.data.vector = vector;` would allow you to keep each line's original vector. And you can set the length of a line to a specific length with the following:

```
var v = line.data.vector.clone();
v.length = 10;         // specific length
line.segments[1].point = p0 - v;
```

Comment: If this answers your question I would appreciate an accept. If it doesn't let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for never accepting this. I think I was confused by all the steps initially, but as it did answer my question I have accepted it. Thanks!